# Concatenate String in Array of Integers in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, concatenation

I'm looking to add a string at the end of each object in an array of type int.

_finalQuestionArray is 8-value array of integers [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]

_card1Type  is a string @"o"

_card1Type  is a string @"p"

I'd like to make a new array of strings that looks like [2o, 3o, 4o, 1o, 2p, 3p, 4p, 1p] but I'm stuck. How can I concatenate the strings to the ints in the array?

Here's my code so far:
// This function appends letters corresponding to the card type here

```
for (int i=0; i<[_finalQuestionArray count]; i++){

    if(i<([_finalQuestionArray count]/2)){

        [[_finalQuestionArray objectAtIndex:i]stringByAppendingString:_card1Type];

    } else {

        [[_finalQuestionArray objectAtIndex:i]stringByAppendingString:_card2Type];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

If you learn by example check the following below,

```
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *cardType1 = @"o";
NSStrind *cardType2 = @"p";

NSArray *array = @[ @2, @3, @4, @1, @2, @3, @4, @1];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

  if (idx < (array.count / 2)) {
    [finalArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", obj, cardType1]];
  } else {
    [finalArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", obj, cardType2]];
  }

}];

NSLog(@"%@", finalArray);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and was a great help! Thanks for answering my first stack question! :)

Answer (score 0):

He wants a string, not an array:

```
NSMutableArray *_finalQuestionArray =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@2, @3, @4, @1, @2, @3, @4, @1]];
NSString *_card1Type = @"o";
NSString *_card2Type = @"p";
NSString *finalString = @"[";

for (int i=0; i<[_finalQuestionArray count]; i++){

    if(i<([_finalQuestionArray count]/2)){

        finalString = [finalString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _finalQuestionArray[i], _card1Type]];


    } else {

        finalString = [finalString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _finalQuestionArray[i], _card2Type]];

    }
    finalString = (i == [_finalQuestionArray count]- 1) ?[finalString stringByAppendingString:@"]"] : [finalString stringByAppendingString:@", "];
}
```

Comment: Hey Julian, sorry for the lack of clarity, but I meant I was looking for a resulting array of strings like [2o, 3o, 4o, 1o, 2p, 3p, 4p, 1p]. Thank you!